# Problem with create Bounty?

Tags: discussion, search

I know this is not a drupal.stackexchange question, but I do have a question on which I am trying to grant bounty. I have 50+ Rep so I want to create a bounty for that question:

[Fuzzy Search in Drupal 7 gives no results](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/125269/fuzzy-search-in-drupal-7-gives-no-results)

I do not see "Start a bounty" option for this question, can someone please quickly guide me what is wrong here?

PS: Moderators can delete this question after someone has guided me on how to open a bounty for this question.

Also, I have tried reading FAQ etc. for bounties, everywhere it is mentioned that question once eligible we can create bounty from 50 to 500 reps, but I don't see that option anywhere!

Comment: Looks like a well described, decent question. We need more of this. I've put a bounty on for you, keep the points you've got so you can comment etc. shan't do this every time so if you're likely to need to start more bounties, pay it forward and participate where you can in the site :)

Comment: Thanks @Clive! So very kind of you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You don't have reputation to set bounty](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). It takes 75 rep to set a bounty, so at the moment you need 6 more.